# pass multiple checkboxes to php

Tags: php, sql

I have a form with multiple checkboxes. On submit I want to be able to take the checkboxes and be able to store them in sql. the foreach that I am using is not working and I have tried many other ways but none have worked. Please help thank you!

[Image of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwUVe.png)

I updated my code since the beginning of my post to troubleshoot problems, but still receiving problems.

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
    include_once 'includes/functions.php';
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['Submitme'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['flight'])){
            print_r($_POST);
            foreach($_POST['flight'] as $key=>$selected){
                echo $selected."</br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

---

```
                <div class="plane">
  <div class="cockpit" >
    <h1>Please select a seat</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="exit exit--front fuselage text-center">
  </div>
  <form action="flightselect.php" method="post" name="form"> 
  <ol class="cabin fuselage">
    <li class="row row--1" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1A" value="1A" />
          <label for="1A">1A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1B" value="1B" />
          <label for="1B">1B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1C" value="1C" />
          <label for="1C">1C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1D" value="1D" />
          <label for="1D">1D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1E" value="1E" />
          <label for="1E">1E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="1F" value="1F" />
          <label for="1F">1F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--2" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2A" value="2A" />
          <label for="2A">2A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2B" value="2B" />
          <label for="2B">2B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2C" value="2C" />
          <label for="2C">2C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2D" value="2D" />
          <label for="2D">2D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2E" value="2E" />
          <label for="2E">2E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2F" value="2F" />
          <label for="2F">2F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--3" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3A" value="3A" />
          <label for="3A">3A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3B" value="3B" />
          <label for="3B">3B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3C" value="3C" />
          <label for="3C">3C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3D" value="3D" />
          <label for="3D">3D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3E" value="3E" />
          <label for="3E">3E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="3F" value="3F" />
          <label for="3F">3F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--4" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4A" value="4A" />
          <label for="4A">4A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4B" value="4B" />
          <label for="4B">4B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4C" value="4C" />
          <label for="4C">4C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4D" value="4D" />
          <label for="4D">4D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4E" value="4E" />
          <label for="4E">4E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="4F" value="4F" />
          <label for="4F">4F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--5" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5A" value="5A" />
          <label for="5A">5A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5B" value="5B" />
          <label for="5B">5B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5C" value="5C" />
          <label for="5C">5C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5D" value="5D" />
          <label for="5D">5D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5E" value="5E" />
          <label for="5E">5E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="5F" value="5F" />
          <label for="5F">5F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--6" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6A" value="6A" />
          <label for="6A">6A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6B" value="6B" />
          <label for="6B">6B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6C" value="6C" />
          <label for="6C">6C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6D" value="6D" />
          <label for="6D">6D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6E" value="6E" />
          <label for="6E">6E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="6F" value="6F" />
          <label for="6F">6F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--7" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7A" value="7A" />
          <label for="7A">7A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7B" value="7B" />
          <label for="7B">7B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7C" value="7C" />
          <label for="7C">7C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7D" value="7D" />
          <label for="7D">7D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7E" value="7E" />
          <label for="7E">7E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="7F" value="7F" />
          <label for="7F">7F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--8" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8A" value="8A" />
          <label for="8A">8A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8B" value="8B" />
          <label for="8B">8B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8C" value="8C" />
          <label for="8C">8C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8D" value="8D" />
          <label for="8D">8D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8E" value="8E" />
          <label for="8E">8E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="8F" value="8F" />
          <label for="8F">8F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--9" style="padding-left: 15%;">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9A" value="9A" />
          <label for="9A">9A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9B" value="9B" />
          <label for="9B">9B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9C" value="9C" />
          <label for="9C">9C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9D" value="9D" />
          <label for="9D">9D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9E" value="9E" />
          <label for="9E">9E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="9F" value="9F" />
          <label for="9F">9F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--10" style="padding-left: 4%";>
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10A" value="10A" />
          <label for="10A">10A</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10B" value="10B" />
          <label for="10B">10B</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10C" value="10C" />
          <label for="10C">10C</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10D" value="10D" />
          <label for="10D">10D</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10E" value="10E" />
          <label for="10E">10E</label>
        </li>
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10F" value="10F" />
          <label for="10F">10F</label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <div class="exit exit--back fuselage">    
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="seatme" value="Submit" style="font-weight: bold;">
</form>
```

Comment: where are you setting the `$_POST['SubmitFlight']` on the form?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Have you debugged the content of `$_POST` in your file?

Comment: im not getting anything as an output. and i updated where the form ended and i have my submit button.

Comment: after the `if(isset($_POST['SubmitFlight'])){` add this line `die('The script died');` and then submit the form, do you see 'The script died' message?

Comment: No, its just a blank screen on flightselect.php

Comment: It's blank because the `$_POST['SubmitFlight']` is not set anywhere, add this `<input type="hidden" name="SubmitFlight" value="1">` after `<form action="flightselect.php" method="post" name="form"> ` add try again

Comment: Provide the value of the checkboxes `<input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="10A" value="10A" />`

Comment: Okay, i added the hidden input and added values to each checkbox. when i submit the script still died.

Comment: StephenMichaelSchintgen what is shown? blank screen?

Comment: I think you're given the submit button name attribute the wrong value. You're checking `$_POST['Submitme']` but the submit button is called `$_POST['seatme']`. If you correct that the code inside the brackets will run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to provide value to you `checkboxes` just provide value to all the checkbox and then try again.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="flight[]" id="2A" value='2A' />
```

Change your PHP part to below

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
    include_once 'includes/functions.php';
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['SubmitFlight'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['flight'])){
            foreach($_POST['flight'] as $key=>$selected){
                echo $selected."</br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: invalid argument on my foreach loop now; if(isset($_POST['SubmitFlight'])){//to run PHP script on submit
if(!empty($_POST['flight'])){
// Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
foreach($_POST['flight'] as $selected){
echo $selected."</br>";
}
}
}

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.12-0\apache2\htdocs\Airways\flightselect.php on line 10

Comment: what output do you get in `$_POST['flight']` check using `print_r`

Comment: my output is SubmitFlight

Comment: it should be the values from the checkbox

Comment: just try `print_r($_POST)` and let me know the output

Comment: Array ( [SubmitFlight] => 1 [flight] => SubmitFlight ) 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.12-0\apache2\htdocs\Airways\flightselect.php on line 11

Comment: change your submit name to anything else you have given the `flight` name to your submit button

Comment: I changed the submit name to seatme. and changed the first post to submit. im getting a blank white screen on submit.

Comment: can u pelase update that changes in your question and no need of that hidden field and check using `print_r($_POST)` once again

Comment: updated my whole code above, still getting white screen so i cant see what post prints.

Comment: you have set button name to `seatme` so it needs to be `isset($_POST['seatme'])` instead of `isset($_POST['Submitme'])` please change and then check if will work for sure

Comment: Ha, it works! Now i have to figure out how im going to insert that into sql database and mark them as taken so people cant pick them